# Create a PostgreSQL view from a unique list of exploded data

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, unnest, lateral-join

When I make this request:

```
SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE mycol IS NOT NULL;
```

I get results like this:

```
foo / bar / hello
foo / hello
foo / bar
```

Each line has values separated with `/` (space, slash, space).

How to create a view with a list of unique values with count ?

```
bar 2
foo 3
hello 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string to rows with `regexp_split_to_table()` in a lateral join, then aggregate:

```
select x.val, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.mycol, '\s/\s') as x(val)
group by x.val
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3c8a08a454767648736fb7c31af5ea22)**:

```
val   | cnt
:---- | --:
bar   |   2
foo   |   3
hello |   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of `string_to_array` and `unnest` to achieve this.

Try Below Query

```sql
select 
unnest(string_to_array(mycol,' / ')), count(*) 
from mytable 
where mycol IS NOT NULL 
group by 1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9b6e6e5d4fc4ca67ecf2439ab2af4faa)

Comment: Elegant request but 4~5 times slower than @GMB request.